# How can i change the Delim in echo Render?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-echo

i am trying to change the delimiter for go in an html template. Unfortunately, it does not work in the render function, nor in the main function.

See https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Delims

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

type Template struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    t.templates.Delims("[[", "]]")
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}
func Hello(c echo.Context) error {
    test := `{
        "name" : "Ben",
        "country" : "Germany",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "body":{"test":"test","test2":"test2"}
    }`
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "hello", test)
}

func main() {
    // Echo instance
    e := echo.New()

    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("public/views/*.html")),
    }
    t.templates.Delims("[[", "]]")
    e.Renderer = t
    e.GET("/hello", Hello)
    // Middleware
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())

    // Start server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8000"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `Delims` before `ParseGlob`.
like this:

```golang
    t := &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.New("").Delims("[[", "]]").ParseGlob("public/views/*.html")),
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, if i change the code a little bit (hello changed to hello.html):

return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "hello.html", test)